# Form not responding to CSS as expected

Tags: html, css

Nothing is happening when I change the value of `left`, `top`, `right`. It stays at the same place. I also tried changing the `position` attribute but nothing is happening.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.PHP_A {
  position: static;
  left: 200px;
  top: 400px;
  right: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ccccff;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
```

```html
<div class="PHP_A">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    Course Name:PHP_A</br>
    </br>
    Course Duration:100 HOURS</br>
    </br>
    CourseFees:$1000</br>
    </br>
    </br>
    </br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="APPLY" />
  </form>
</div>
</br>
</br>
```

Comment: According to documentation for `position:static`: "The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document. The top, right, bottom, left, and z-index properties have no effect. This is the default value." See [position @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Values).

Comment: Your position is static, adjusting top, left or the other 2 will not do anything when position is static

Comment: I checked by removing the position attribute also

Comment: The commenters are correct-- if you want to move the form relative to its current position use `position: relative`; if you want to position it relative to the first relatively positioned parent use `position: absolute`.

Comment: To help clarify, please describe specifically how you want to position the element.

Comment: Incidentally, there is no `</br>` element; I suggest `<br>` instead. See [What is the main difference of <br> and </br>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28512655/what-is-the-main-difference-of-br-and-br) and [HTML 5: Is it <br>, <br/>, or <br />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to change position `static` to position `absolute` or even position `fixed` that will depend on your use case.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

> **static**: Default value. Elements render in order, as they appear in the document flow
>
> **absolute**: The element is positioned relative to its first positioned (not static) ancestor element
>
> **fixed**: The element is positioned relative to the browser window

```html
<style>
.PHP_A
{
  position: absolute;
  left: 200px;
  top: 400px;
  right: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ccccff;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;   
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
</style>
<div class="PHP_A">
  <form action="#" method="post">
    Course Name: PHP_A </br></br>
    Course Duration: 100 HOURS </br></br>
    CourseFees: $1000 </br></br>
    </br></br> 
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="APPLY" />
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the portion of the code "**position:static**;" was the problem it was making your div to align in a pre defined structure css of document flow, instead you should use "**position:relative**" I have modified your css a little bit now you can give any value to left or right and see the result

```
<style>
.PHP_A
{
  position:absolute;
  left: 10%;
  top: 40px;
  right: 200px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #ccccff;
  max-width: 360px;
  margin: 0 auto 100px;
  padding: 45px;
  text-align: center;   
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 5px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
}
</style>
```